# My MongoDB database connection does not re-open upon closing

Tags: mongodb, next.js, mongodb-atlas, next-auth

I'm implementing an Authentication system with NextAuth inside of my Next.js app.
I'm using NextAuth Credentials as the provider with my custom login screen.

I'm using NextAuth v.4.

Previously I have established my connection like represented below:

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

export async function connectToDatabase() {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URI, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });

    return client;
}
```

I then went ahead to call it inside the `authorize` function within the `[...nextauth].js` file. Here is a snippet:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import { connectToDatabase } from "../../../lib/database";
import { verifyPassword } from "../../../lib/auth";

export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            authorize: async (credentials) => {

                const client = await connectToDatabase();
                const db = client.db();

                const user = await db.collection('users').findOne({ email: credentials.email });

                if (!user) {
                    client.close();
                    throw new Error("User not found.");
                }

                const isValid = await verifyPassword(credentials.password, user.password);

                if (!isValid) {
                    client.close();
                    throw new Error("Invalid username or password.");
                }

                client.close();

                return { email: user.email, username: user.username, name: user.name };
            }
        }),
    ],
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    jwt: {
        secret: "SOME_SECRET",
    }
});
```

Now the above works as expected, however, it's extremely slow with the database requests. Also, I've looked into the MongoDB official guide of creating a database connection, and this is what they suggested I use:

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

const uri = process.env.DATABASE_URI;
const options = {
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
}

let client;
let clientPromise;

if (!process.env.DATABASE_URI) {
  throw new Error('Please add your Mongo URI to .env.local');
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  if (!global._mongoClientPromise) {
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
    global._mongoClientPromise = client.connect();
  }
  clientPromise = global._mongoClientPromise;
} else {
  client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
  clientPromise = client.connect();
}

export default clientPromise;
```

From here I went onto importing the client and establishing the connection differently:

```
import clientPromise from "../../../lib/database";
```

And here is how I initialise the connection:

```
const client = await clientPromise;
const db = client.db();
```

This has significantly improved my MongoDB speed by x10. From around 400ms per fetch request, down to around 40ms or less. This was great.

Now onto the actual problem.

Everytime I close the connection with `client.close()`, while using the `clientPromise` implementation, it never reconnects again on any other of the opening connections.

The error I get is:

```
MongoNotConnectedError: MongoClient must be connected to perform this operation.
```

It can never connect again with any other operation on my App. Even the connections which are unrelated to Authentication. Am I missing something?

I have tried switching between the old and new implementation, which narrowed down to the fact that it's a problem with the new implementation. But I can't understand what's causing it.

Comment: Do you see these connections alive on the database end with `db.serverStatus().connections`? After `client.close()` is invoked & another attempt is made to reconnect.

Comment: It says ```client.db().serverStatus``` is not a function

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit late but I've managed to solve a similar issue with prepending an await keyword to db method. Maybe this could help another one.

So, please replace

```
const db = client.db();
```

with

```
const db = await client.db();
```